# Waiting for user input multiple times in single script

Tags: bash

When I run the script below:

1. screen cleared
2. wait for any key press
3. change directory
4. run `start.sh`

Why doesn't the script "wait for any key press" between `3` and `4`?

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

pause(){
  read -n1
}

clear
pause

echo "cd /home/bob/git/someproject"
cd /home/bob/git/someproject
pause

./start.sh
```

Comment: What key are you pressing? Some keys emit multiple characters.

Comment: I blindly tested with arrow keys, space works :)

Comment: Arrow keys send escape sequences, not a single character.